# Running git fetch in batch file via c# process hangs up

Tags: c#, git, batch-file

I am trying to run several git commands via c# and continuing to work with the resulting outputs.

I wrote this little Method to work with:

```
private string runGitCommand(string gitCommand, string path)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.FileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath+"\\gitcommand.bat";
        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        processInfo.Arguments = gitCommand;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = processInfo;
        string output="";
        process.OutputDataReceived += (a, b) => {
            Console.WriteLine(b.Data);
            output += b.Data;
        }
        ;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (a, b) => Console.WriteLine(b.Data);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

        return output;
    }
```

sure thing, some settings are for debugging (like the unneccessary `Console.WriteLine()`) but it works with most git commands like `status` or `rev-parse HEAD`.

This is my batch-file I use:

```
@"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/git.exe" %1 %2
```

There are two arguments since `rev-parse HEAD` are two arguments.
I don't have any Problems executing `status` so this double arguments shouldn't be the problem.

Everything works exactly like intended but when I execute `fetch` the program hangs up.

I used the batch file in cmd with same inputs and it did take its time (about 1-2 seconds) but it exited without any problems (no output was given there).

any thoughts?

Comment: Depends entirely on the repo and its configuration, but it's likely waiting for user input. What happens when you execute the same command (verbatim) on the terminal? Do you get an authentication prompt?

Comment: you should post your comment as an answer ^^
this was exactly the issue, apparently, only git commands, that contact the server do have the problem with RSA Authentication (since I crapply copied the repo for testing purposes).
So yes there was a waiting for a user input. Any idea how I can check if the program is waiting for user inputs?

Comment: _Any idea how I can check if the program is waiting for user inputs._ If you're writing this code as anything other than quick prototyping, I'd go with something more robust (like [libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki)), which is a very round-about way of saying "I don't know" ;)

Comment: Don't add the solution to the question, post it as an answer instead as that's what they are for! It's absolutely no problem to answer your own question, you may even accept your own answer later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a not working RSA authentication.
Since `git fetch` contacts the server and `git status` not, this error could only be seen by typing the used commands by hand in cmd (not git bash).

The program was waiting for user input. As suggested by @ardila the usage of [lib2git](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki) should be used for a robust use of git in C#.