# Git diff between 2 tags without full fetch fails running using git-bash.exe

Tags: c#, vb.net, git, git-diff, git-for-windows

I am trying to run git-cmd.exe from my code using `Process`. Below commands when passed to git-cmd.exe runs successfully when the `git diff` is happening between 2 branches.

```
git init
git remote add origin "<repo-name>"
git fetch origin <branch1>
git fetch origin <branch2>
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d <branch1>:<folder1> <branch2>:<folder1>
```

I need to find the file names which were modified or added in `<folder1>` only, between the given branches. I am executing these commands by passing them as a `string[]` to a function.

```
Public Function RunAndReturnExitCode(ByVal Command As String(), ByVal Directory As String,
                                         Optional ByVal MaximumWaitTime As Integer = -1,
                                         Optional ByRef Output As String = Nothing,
                                         Optional ByRef Errors As String = Nothing) As String
        Dim exePath As String = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PortableGit\git-cmd.exe"
        Dim si As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(exePath)
        si.RedirectStandardInput = True
        si.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        si.RedirectStandardError = True
        si.UseShellExecute = False
        si.WorkingDirectory = Directory

        Dim p As Process = Process.Start(si)

        With p.StandardInput
            .WriteLine("cd /d """ & Directory & """")
            Array.ForEach(Command, Sub(c) .WriteLine(c))
            .WriteLine("exit")
        End With
        p.WaitForExit(MaximumWaitTime)
        Output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        Errors = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
        Return p.ExitCode.ToString()
    End Function
```

Due to performance issues, we have now started working on tags. So, I am now doing:

```
git init
git remote add origin "<repo-name>"
git fetch origin refs/tags/[tag1]
git fetch origin refs/tags/[tag2]
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d [tag1]:[folder1] [tag2]:[folder1]
```

Here, the diff command fails by:

> fatal: Invalid object name '[tag1]'.

I tried running a few commands manually from `git-cmd.exe`, where I found `git checkout refs/tags/[tag1]` itself failed by:

> error: pathspec '[tag1]' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Does this mean that my local repository does not have any info of `[tag1]`? If not, then why was there no error while fetching them? Can anyone suggest here, how I can fetch only these 2 tags and do a diff between them?

Tried [git diff tag1 tag2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/how-to-compare-two-tags-with-git), but its failing by :

> fatal: ambiguous argument '[tag1]': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Please please let me know if any more inputs are required here from me. Also, I can not do a `git fetch --tags` as it hangs (I suppose, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476940/running-git-fetch-in-batch-file-via-c-sharp-process-hangs-up) is not the issue here as fetching the tags separately does not hang). To add, my organization does not permit usage of https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @torek, a `git fetch refs/tags/tag1` was a wrong approach. I have now updated it to:

```
git fetch origin +refs/tags/tag1:refs/tags/tag1 +refs/tags/tag2:refs/tags/tag2
```

The command works fine on `git-cmd.exe` and I am able to get the diff. But it hangs when I fire through a `process`. My SSH repository does not have a pass-phrase, so it is for sure that the `RSA Aunthentication` isn't failing. Any suggestions here? Am I firing the commands correctly via the process?

Comment: Doing a `git pull --tags` before doing the diff also hangs my process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> git fetch origin refs/tags/[tag1]

is wrong as it obtains the desired *commit* but does not write any *name* in your repository.  The commit is now available through `FETCH_HEAD`, but only until the next `git fetch`.  That is:

> git fetch origin refs/tags/[tag2]

obtains *that* desired commit, but overwrites `FETCH_HEAD`, so that now the only name you have—`FETCH_HEAD`—refers only to the *second* desired commit.

To fix this, you could either fetch both and discard their tag names, but now have both hash IDs in `FETCH_HEAD` (you would have to retrieve them yourself), or you can direct `git fetch` to *create or update* your `refs/tags/tag1` and `refs/tags/tag2` names:

```
git fetch origin +refs/tags/tag1:refs/tags/tag1 +refs/tags/tag2:refs/tags/tag2
```

The colon and second name provide the name of the reference to create-or-update in *your* Git repository.  The leading plus sign `+` here tells `git fetch` that this particular update should be forced, i.e., it should overwrite any previous tag of the same name.

Of course, `git fetch --tags` should work.  (`git pull --tags` means *run `git fetch --tags`, then run a second Git command, probably `git merge`*.  If you don't want to run any second Git command automatically, don't use `git pull`.)  If this hangs, it may be worth investigating why: all it does is call up the other Git just like any `git fetch`, but this time also fetch `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.

Comment: The command runs fine if I run separately on git-cmd.exe, but when I call it from a C# process, it hangs. I guess it is waiting for some user input. I tried closing the process.StandardInput.Close() as suggested by one of the SO answers. Since I am using SSH repositories, the authentication is also happening through the RSA keys. Is there any different way of debugging this?

Comment: I don't use Windows, nor C#, but closing the process's stdin is ... well, not *unreasonable*, but in the Linux world, you'd set its stdin to point to `/dev/null` instead. If you're using a Linux-like ssh, though, and if the key that ssh needs is passphrase-protected, you'll need an agent to pass the key through, otherwise ssh will open `/dev/tty` (or whatever the Windows equivalent may be) and request the passphrase.

Comment: Ok. Well, I am bound to use a Windows box, and the SSH does not have a passphrase currently. Let me edit my question instead of opening a new one. The real problem here is I guess that my process is waiting for some kind of input.